# Note: vm_service is pinned to version 13.0.0 by flutter_test from the flutter SDK. How to solve this problem

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

I am working a flutter project. suddendy I pugrade my flutter sdk by using command prompt "flutter upgrade". After the update complete, I oppend this project with Android Studio.When I run this project or try to Resolving dependencies then it's show me this problem in console which is "Note: vm_service is pinned to version 13.0.0 by flutter_test from the flutter SDK".

How to fix this problem.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.